# Simple statistics for measuring binary time series characteristics

Tags: time-series, binary-data

Which statistical metrics can be used for characterizing binary time series?

For the classical time series there is this paper:

> S. Wang and R. Hyndman "Rule induction for forecasting method
>   selection: meta-​​​​learning the characteristics of univariate time
>   series,” Neurocomputing, 72, 2581–2594, 2009

But for binary time series I do not know any publication.

Answer (score 2):

If the time series consists of 0s and 1s, the simplest statistics to compute are

- Proportion of 1s
- Proportion of 1s that follow 0s
- Proportion of 0s that follow 0s

There is no need, of course, for the corresponding proportions as they are simply calculated from these. The latter two define the transition matrix for the associated Markov chain, and roughly correspond to autocorrelation measures.

You might also look at run lengths (e.g., number of "111" or "000" relative to length of the series).

Answer (score 0):

I know that Benjamin Kedem wrote a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824769201) on binary time series.  Maybe some of what you are looking for can be found there.